# Not able to use __ANDROID__ macro in Shared Assest Project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, xamarin-studio

I am new in Xamarin.form. I had create Xamarin SAP project and in SAP trying use to plaform specific api for which i am using macro. 
**iOS** macro is visible but **ANDROID** macro is not visible.

I have to do some project setting for that?

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the Droid project, click Options, go to the Compiler section and add it in the Define Symbols field. If iOS works, double check to see how it is configured in that project.

Comment: for iOS complier define symbol is __UNIFIED__;__MOBILE__;__IOS__;DEBUG;ENABLE_TEST_CLOUD; for android complier define symbol is                  DEBUG;____ANDROID____;

Comment: OK, so for Android add `__ANDROID__` in the same spot, but now in the Android project options

Comment: thanks for reply still facing issue with macro usage in xamarin-form project. still not getting __Android__ macro.

Comment: I'm sorry but if you don't provide me with any more information, I can't help you any further